# MUI DataGrid - Select all rows on the current page only

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

in MUI paid version there is a `checkboxSelectionVisibleOnly` prop.
How to achieve the same with the community/free version?

I am using `v6`.
This is what I have so far, but when I select single row it selects all rows.

The goal is to select All Rows on current page only

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqwtC.png)

If I'm on another page it should add rows to the currently selected ones

````
onRowSelectionModelChange={(rowSelectionModel) => {
              // user cleared selection
              if (rowSelectionModel.length === 0) {
                return setSelectedRows([]);
              }

              const {
                state: {
                  rowSelection,
                  pagination: {
                    paginationModel: { page, pageSize },
                  },
                },
              } = apiRef.current;

              // user unchecked row
              if (rowSelectionModel.length < rowSelection.length) {
                return setSelectedRows(rowSelectionModel);
              }

              const startIndex = page * pageSize;
              const endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
              const currentPageRows = apiRef.current
                .getAllRowIds()
                .slice(startIndex, endIndex);

              // no selection yet, select rows from current page
              if (rowSelection.length === 0) {
                // limit selection to current page rather than ALL table entries
                return setSelectedRows(currentPageRows);
              }

              const currentSelection = new Set(rowSelection);

              // user selected single row, maybe on another page?
              currentPageRows.forEach((row) => {
                if (currentSelection.has(row)) {
                  currentSelection.delete(row);
                } else {
                  currentSelection.add(row);
                }
              });
              return setSelectedRows(Array.from(currentSelection));
            }}```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
export const checkboxSelectionVisibleOnly = ({
  apiRef,
  rowSelectionModel,
}: {
  apiRef: GridApi;
  rowSelectionModel: GridRowSelectionModel;
}): GridRowSelectionModel => {
  const {
    state: {
      rowSelection,
      pagination: {
        paginationModel: { page, pageSize },
      },
    },
  } = apiRef;

  // no selection yet, select rows from current page
  if (rowSelection.length === 0) {
    // user clicked on "All" checkbox
    if (rowSelectionModel.length > 1) {
      const startIndex = page * pageSize;
      const endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
      return apiRef.getAllRowIds().slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    } else {
      // user clicked on specific row
      return rowSelectionModel;
    }
  }

  // user unchecked row(s)
  if (rowSelectionModel.length < rowSelection.length) {
    return rowSelectionModel;
  }

  return rowSelectionModel;
};
```